# UIButton Highlight issue

Tags: iphone

I have an UIButton in my application.

I want to show a selection of my button. I am using this code:

```
[Button setHighlighted:YES];
```

But it's not working.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by having two images for button. One for highlighted state and one for normal state. When you create the button, create with normal state image as buttons background image. And when you select or focus on the button, change the image as highlighted background image.

```
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage backgroundImage:@"ButtonSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage backgroundImage:@"ButtonNormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNoraml]
```

Answer (score 0):

See these posts.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=530998

http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/2/5/how_to_make_an_iphone/